# Bar plot with heatmap color palette

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a simple bar plot using `matplotlib.pyplot` and `seaborn` libraries. Is it possible to change a color scheme of bars in such a way that bars corresponding to higher counts would have darker red color, while bars of low counts have light red colors? So, some kind of a heatmap applied to bar plot. How can I do it? Currently, I have random colors in my count plot.

```
df =
    DeviceId   Speed
    1          30
    1          35 
    1          31
    2          20
    2          25
    3          80

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib inline

result = df.groupby(["DeviceId"])['Speed'].aggregate(np.median).reset_index()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.barplot(x="DeviceId", y="Speed", data=result)
plt.ylabel('Median speed', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Device ID', fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
sns.barplot(x="DeviceId", y="Speed", data=result, palette=sns.cubehelix_palette(8))
```

but darker colors do not correspond to higher count numbers. It looks like colors are assigned randomly to bars using a predefined color palette.

Comment: there is a typo on this line command: result = df.groupby(["DeviceId"])'Speed'].aggregate(np.median).reset_index()  ("]")

Comment: @edouard: Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may obtain the colors according to a colormap by defining a normalization instance with the minimum and maximum data value and map the data to a color using this normalization and a colormap of choice. Here, using the reversed copper map may make sense (see [colormap reference](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html))

```
norm = plt.Normalize(result["Speed"].values.min(), result["Speed"].values.max())
colors = plt.cm.copper_r(norm(result["Speed"]))
```

You can then use those colors in the barplot

```
sns.barplot(x="DeviceId", y="Speed", data=result, palette=colors)
```

[image]

Complete code to reproduce the above:

```
u = u"""DeviceId   Speed
    1          30
    1          35 
    1          31
    2          20
    2          25
    3          80"""

import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)
result = df.groupby(["DeviceId"])['Speed'].aggregate(np.median).reset_index()

norm = plt.Normalize(result["Speed"].values.min(), result["Speed"].values.max())
colors = plt.cm.copper_r(norm(result["Speed"]))

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.barplot(x="DeviceId", y="Speed", data=result, palette=colors)
plt.ylabel('Median speed', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Device ID', fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Normalizing from `0` on may also have a nice effect with any of the sequential colormaps,

```
norm = plt.Normalize(0, result["Speed"].values.max())
colors = plt.cm.Purples(norm(result["Speed"]))
```

[image]

Comment: Great. How can I do a red color map?

Comment: Maybe you look into the colormaps from the link provided and try some out. If the result is not what you like, ask a little more specific about it.

Answer (score 0):

for Python 3.x the norm step has to be adjusted:

```
u = u"""DeviceId   Speed
    1          01
    1          09
    1          31
    2          20
    2          25
    3          80"""

import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
#%matplotlib inline
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)

df     = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)
result = df.groupby(["DeviceId"])['Speed'].aggregate(np.median).reset_index()

norm   = plt.Normalize(0, result["Speed"].values.max())
colors = plt.cm.RdYlGn(   result["Speed"].apply(norm ))

fig    = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax     = sns.barplot(x="DeviceId", y="Speed", data=result, palette=colors,  )

_ = plt.ylabel('Median speed', fontsize=12)
_ = plt.xlabel('Device ID'   , fontsize=12)
_ = plt.xticks(rotation= 90 )
plt.show()
```

[image]